# SMF displays raw HTML and PHP on browser

Tags: php, html, smf-forum

I am new to SMF.

I just installed SMF on my website. I tried editing the index.template.php . After saving changes, it displays raw HTML and PHP on the browser. I tried fixing the prob by returning the the page back to the original state  to no avail.

At the moment, everything is gibberish both frontend and backend.

Pls what do i do?

Comment: did you delete the open tag (`<?php`)? Also what did you use to edit it?

Comment: @prodigitalson , i worked on the functions: template main above and template main below ; i did not see any php opening or closing tag

Comment: there should be at least an open tag at the top of the file (at the top of every .php file) - is there one there? Also what application did you use to edit the file?

Comment: @prodigitalson : thanks i actually deleted <?php

Comment: No problem. I have submitted my comment again as an answer `<nudge-nudge />` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be at least an open tag at the top of the file (at the top of every .php file). Make sure you didn't remove this tag. Everything outside of a `<?php` is interpreted as normal text so if you have removed this it would explain your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also, being an ex-team member for SMF I can assure you its better to create a copy of the default theme, then make your edits to that theme. Then if you experience an error you can always pass a param in the url to reset to the default theme (in case you need to get into the admin area). To do so end the url with index.php?theme=1